# hash table with integer as keys

Tags: c++, boost

A hash function transform a Key into an integer hash value, is it possible to have an integer as a Key ?

with boost::hash function it seems I get the same integer for the hash value...so I am a little bit in trouble

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for a cryptographic hash? That's a different thing altogether.

Comment: yes I just realize I misunderstanding some concept, I would like to optimize things but that lead me into an impass

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With integers that wouldn't be a problem, would it? Equal input values would produce the same hash-value, and distinct input values produce distinct hash-values. This is the perfect hash-function!

Comment: what you described are the *minimum* requirements for a hash function. In fact, it doesn't even have to create distinct values... so I wouldn't call it *perfect* :)

Comment: @yi_H: The identity function (which the OP describes) is certainly a perfect hash-function.

Comment: I didn't realize you use it as a technical term.. probably because you used 'the'

Answer (score 4):

If you look up the actual implementation of the `std::hash` (e.g. in `functional_hash.h` or something like that) for the primitive types, you will see that for most of the integral types it is simply the identity function! Since the hash function is purely for mathematical and not for cryptographic purposes, there is no requirement that it be a "random" map to the range, so the identity is indeed perfectly appropriate.